# Doctrine2 / orm:schema-tool:update execute each time the same query

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a `Client` entity with a unique index on the `reference` property / table column.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="clients", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="client_reference_idx", columns={"reference"}, options={"where": "(reference IS NOT NULL) AND (reference <> '')"})})
 *
 */
class Client
{
    //...
```

On EACH `orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql | --force`, index is droped / created ...

```
DROP INDEX client_reference_idx;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX client_reference_idx ON clients (reference) WHERE (reference IS NOT NULL) AND (reference <> '');
```

I have other entities with unique constraint but only this one have a constraints with a `WHERE` clause.

What's wrong ?